# Help evaluating a surface $(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2=2z\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ for using it in triple integral

Tags: integration, surfaces, multiple-integral

So the surface $S$ is defined as:

$$(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2=2z\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

And i have to look at the object it surrounds in $\mathbb{R^3}$
So it seems I'd be using spherical coordinates in the calculation(since the left side is somehow just the equation of sphere squared). But i wonder how does the surface look like, I have to draw a sketch of it.
Is it still similar to a sphere?

So using spherical coordinates gives me:
$$x=r\cos\phi \cos\theta$$
$$x=r\sin\phi \cos\theta$$
$$x=r\sin\theta$$

So because of left sides sphere-like appearence  for $$\phi\in[0,2\pi]$$

Also : $$r\leq \sin\theta \cos\theta(\sin\phi+\cos\phi)$$

So i need help getting bounds for $\theta$ as well as for any isnigth how to draw this object/surface.
On the other hand is my approach correct? All that is left after that is calculating the integrals needed for getting the centre of mass, that i have covered.

Thank you for any help and hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the solid:
$$
\Omega 
:= \left\{ (x,\,y,\,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : 
\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^2 \le 2\,z\,\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\,\right\}
$$

[image]

applying the following *coordinate transformation*:
$$
\Phi :
\begin{cases}
x = \rho\,\sin\varphi\,\cos\theta \\
y = \rho\,\sin\varphi\,\sin\theta \\
z = \rho\,\cos\varphi
\end{cases} 
\; \; \; \; \; \; \text{with} \; (\rho,\,\varphi,\,\theta) \in [0,\,+\infty) \times [0,\,\pi] \times [0,\,2\pi)
$$
and $J_{\Phi} = \rho^2\,\sin\varphi$, it follows that:
$$
\begin{cases}
\rho^4 \le \rho^2\,\sin(2\varphi) \\
\rho \ge 0 \\
0 \le \varphi \le \pi \\
0 \le \theta < 2\pi
\end{cases}
\; \; \; \; \; \; \Leftrightarrow \; \; \; \; \; \;
\begin{cases}
0 \le \rho \le \sqrt{\sin(2\varphi)} \\
0 \le \varphi \le \frac{\pi}{2} \\
0 \le \theta < 2\pi
\end{cases}
$$
therefore, we have:
$$
\Omega^* 
:= \left\{ (\rho,\,\varphi,\,\theta) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : 
0 \le \rho \le \sqrt{\sin(2\varphi)}, \;
0 \le \varphi \le \frac{\pi}{2}, \;
0 \le \theta < 2\pi\right\}.
$$
In light of all this, we have:
$$
||\Omega|| 
:= \iiint\limits_{\Omega} 1\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y\,\text{d}z
= \iiint\limits_{\Omega^*} J_{\Phi}\,\text{d}\rho\,\text{d}\varphi\,\text{d}\theta = \frac{\pi^2}{8}
$$
$$
\overline{z} 
:= \frac{1}{||\Omega||}\iiint\limits_{\Omega} z\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y\,\text{d}z
= \frac{1}{||\Omega||}\iiint\limits_{\Omega^*} \left(\rho\,\cos\varphi\right)J_{\Phi}\,\text{d}\rho\,\text{d}\varphi\,\text{d}\theta = \frac{4}{3\pi}
$$
which is what is desired. Of course, $\overline{x} = \overline{y} = 0$ for symmetric questions, it is not necessary to integrate.

Comment: May I ask what software you have used for it?

Answer (score 1):

It is clearly axysymmetric with respect to the $z$ axis, so plot it is the $xz$-plane and rotate it.

[image: Plot in the yz-plane]
[image: 3D plot]